# Grammar Mystery or Unlikely Typo?

Tags: grammaticality

I was recently reading a book and came across a sentence that says "Allow me to do *the some* of the same." Should it read "Allow me to do *some* of the same"?

It sounds completely wrong with "the" in there. However, it's in a book about writing by a professional editor. I'm wondering if this dude's some kind of grammar ninja or what. I've tried using Google and even ran it through several "grammar-checkers" and can't find any instance in which you would say it like that.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Seems like an error to me. Books do sometimes have typos.

Comment: The example is from "Write Better: A Lifelong Editor on Craft, Art, and Spirituality" by Andrew T. Le Peau - it is an error that the editor should have seen and corrected. (I suspect that Mr Le Paau acted as his own editor, which is always a mistake...)